# Dealing with Apps Script Properties in AuthMode.NONE

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on an AddOn [based on an Apps Script library](https://script.google.com/d/MarIlVOhstkJA6QjPgCWAHIq9hSqx7jwh/edit?usp=drive_web) which stores several keystrings in the user cache. In testing the AddOn in `AuthMode.NONE`, the menu addition fails because the cache is trying to load when the document opens.

To work around this, I've tried incorporating several of the cache calls right into my code. This hasn't worked either.

Is there a way to programmatically add a library *or* prevent certain `.gs` files from loading in an AddOn until the user has enabled it?

**UPDATE**

Tanaike has a helpful [Manifest library](https://github.com/tanaikech/ManifestsApp#how-to-install) which allows you to change which libraries the app has access to. But, it still leads to authorization limitations. **Is there a way to have the user interactively change the authorization mode?**

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, it has some information about [add-on menus dealing with AuthMode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#menus_for_add-ons_in_google_sheets_docs_or_forms) and [add-on authorization lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this information is useful for you. It is possible to install, update and remove GAS libraries using script. If you want to install libraries using script, you can achieve it by using Manifests(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests). If this was not useful, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm checking out your `ManifestsApp` library to install after the user has enabled the AddOn. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian Thank you for using it. If you have any questions for ManifestsApp, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike Not sure that's going to work, either...still running into authorization errors when loading the Addon in `AuthMode.NONE.` I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: I have a question. Is the project you are sharing used as a library? If it's so, can I see the script at client side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Apps Script addon development flow.

I have released [an addon](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/email_parser_analytics/1064984795246), that follows the code from Apps Script documentation:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Enable Addon', 'startWorkflow');
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

The addon works and when installed from Gsuite Marketplace, the Enable Addon menu correctly appears in AuthMode.None.

However, when tested from inside script editor in AuthMode.None, it fails to add menus correctly with a console info:

```
Script Google Apps: Exception: You don't have permission for this action.
```

I think Google devs should handle it and fix the bug, and it's not meant to be solved by some manifest libraries or something else.